# removed header, now there's a gap

Tags: header

I am working with the twentyfourteen WP theme - I removed the header by using "display: none" but now there is a large empty gap at the top of the site. I guess this is because there is still an empty div there, but I'm not sure why the rest of the content isn't being shifted up.

Site: http://theroadmap.co/generation/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't even a proper question, but here you go.

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Has margin set to 48, set it to 0 using this:

```
#main { margin-top: 0px;}
```